# Server-side Pagination Patterns for Seam?

Tags: database, jsf, pagination, richfaces, seam

I have an application based on JBoss Seam, RichFaces, and Hibernate/JPA.  I've created a DAO class and a couple of business-layer classes that are used to retrieve data based on various criteria.  (Fetch most recent, browse all, etc.)  I'd like to return these results and display them for the user, allowing the user to paginate through them.  However, since the objects returned can be rather large (and there is a large number of objects) I'd prefer not to use something like `<rich:dataList />` and `<rich:datascroller />` which would require me to retrieve all the objects in one large query and maintain them in memory.

Are there any generally-accepted patterns for performing server-side pagination of datasets?  I'm looking for a strategy for:

- Retrieving a subset of my data using a start index and count
- Scroll through the dataset using 'next' and 'previous' buttons, thereby retrieving a new subset of the data using an updated start index and count

Have any of you seen custom DataModel objects that would allow me to use `<rich:dataList />` and `<rich:datascroller />` but still perform server-side pagination using subset queries?  I'd be very curious to learn of your methodologies for handling such a scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an in-built server side pagination in Seam Application Framework. Just have a look at the [EntityQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR3/reference/en-US/html/framework.html#d0e8405) objects.

You can easily extends those classes, and basically get pagination for free when using `getResultList()`

However, before you start extending those classes everywhere, take a look at [this blog post](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-you-should-not-use-seam-application.html).

Comment: Agreed.  But, I've already got DAO classes to handle the data retrieval.  My question is if there are any well-established or generally-accepted patterns for doing server-side pagination that don't involve EntityQuery.

Comment: Yes there are, and it is implemented in the EntityQuery object. Why don't you just look at the source code of how they have done it, and implement the same thing? Basically what you have to do is pass the min and max parameter when you say next page, and set it in your `query.firstResult(min).maxResult(max)`